Notion extensible alternatives
Currently, our company is using Notion, and we have an issue with it not being the best for supporting company processes, as it doesn’t allow much customization or automation of workflows. There are, of course, some efforts from Notion, such as formulas or automation within databases, but these offer very limited possibilities. We are looking for an alternative that includes almost all the functions of Notion and provides opportunities for expansion with custom code and plugins.
For example, it should be possible to implement something like:
Creating a button within a page that, when clicked, runs custom code (e.g., JavaScript):
databases.get("partners").insertPage({title: currentPage.title + " copy" + Date.now().toString()})

